# Redhat No IGMP response

Tags: redhat, multicast, igmp

I'm setting up my server to ingest a multicast.

The server will initiate the request and can join the multicast for about 2:30-3:30 min. After that, it gets dropped from the multicast group due to no IGMP response.

The server is running Redhat 6.9

Route table has the 224.0.0.0. netmask 240.0.0.0 via eth5. I also have the source IP added to the routing table, with the multicast.

I've gone through all of the articles on StackOverflow, and also looked through the Redhat articles and can't find anything that points to the issue.

I'm configured for IGMP V3, and I have the rp_filter turned off.

I've also checked the iptables which are off.

I'm using FFMPEG to pull the stream.